# Reading the file returns nothing (python)

Tags: python

This is part of my code for a simple music quiz. However, file.readline() returns an empty space whenever I run it. There is a text file called storage.txt with the data in it. I have tried using file.seek(), file.read(), and file.readlines() but none so far have allowed me to print a specific line.

```
points = 0
question_number = 0

file = open("storage.txt","r")
while True: 
 question_number = question_number + 1
 keyword = file.readline(question_number)
 print("Who made this song?")
 answer = input(keyword)
 if answer == file.readline(question_number+1):
  print("You got it right, 1 point for you!")
  points += 1
 else:
  print("You lost with",points,"points.")
  break

file.close()
print("All done.")
```

Comment: Can you check the readline definition once?
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readline.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `file.readline()` here is wrong. Check out what parameters the function should get.
[Maybe this could help](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm). `readline()` reads the next line of the file, and not the line specified in the parameter. The parameter is actually `size`, or how many bytes to read of the line. If you want to read a specific line, I'd suggest doing something like this -

```
keyword = file.readlines()[question_number]
```

you might want to refer to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) for how to use the `readlines()` function.

Anyways, I suggest you name your file variable something else, as file is a saved word. Call it something like `my_file`, or `song_titles_file`, or any other meaningful name.